# No Access Permission Assigned Hikvision ISAPI FaceDataRecord

Tags: laravel, upload, isapi, hikvision

I work with Hikvision ISAPI with Laravel, I send a POST request via ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json, I add a photo on the Hikvizhn terminal, but when the user goes through the face ID I get No Access Permission Assigned and when I go in and delete the photo from the terminal and add a photo through the terminal, everything works and I get Authenticated via Face. I don’t understand what my mistake is or what this is connected with

Http::withDigestAuth(config('services.hikvision.username'), config('services.hikvision.password'))
->attach('FaceImage', file_get_contents($request->file('image')), $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName())
->post(config('services.hikvision.url').'/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json', [
'FaceDataRecord' => json_encode([
'faceLibType' => 'blackFD',
'FDID'        => '1',
"FPID"        => str($employee->id),
]),
])->json();